# Angular Routing 1.6 assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

When building this site I took a pure JS approach for the interaction. But now I am trying implement Angular as well, particularly for the routing.

However I am a novice with angular and am struggling with the routing. What I would like to happen is have the new section html load into the `<div ng-view="">` upon click of new page in nav.

This is the error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module stretchFlexViewer due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'stretchFlexViewer' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here is my plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/F6rRQcQtA8lNgLCKmoEj?p=preview

app.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "app.homeCtrl","app.stretchProdCtrl"])

  .config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when("/home", {
        controller: "homeCtrl",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
      })
      .when("/stretchProd", {
        controller: "stretchProdCtrl",
        templateUrl: "stretchProd.html"
      })
      .when("/science", {
        templateUrl: "/science.html"
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/home"
      });
  });
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@2.0.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://unmillennials.com/but.css" />
    <title>Stretch Flex</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top col-xs-12 no-pad">
      <div class="container col-xs-12">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">StretchFlex</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a href="http://stretchflex.net">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="menu_item" href="stretchProd.html">Stretch Producer</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="menu_item" href="science.html">Science</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

homeCtrl

```
var app = angular.module('stretchFlexViewer', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  console.log('This is a test');

});
```

home.html

```
  <section id="content">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 no-pad top-block">
      <img class="top-photo col-lg-12 col-xs-12 no-pad" src="http://stretchflex.net/photos/img5.jpg" alt="tennis" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="comp-name">
      <span class="lightBlue" style="color:#87CEEB;">Stretch</span><span style="color: #D3D3D3;">Flex</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comparison parent">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-pad mov">
        <div class="bordered-image child first">
          <span class="stance-area">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 no-pad">
              <img class="stance" src="http://stretchflex.net/stanceJaphet.jpg" min-height="50%" width="85%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-pad ang1">
              <img class="angle-japhet one"  src="http://stretchflex.net/photos/startAngle.png" min-height="25%" width="100%"/>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span class="stance-area">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  no-pad">
              <img class="stance" src="http://stretchflex.net/stanceBaez.jpg" min-height="50%" width="85%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-pad ang2">
              <img class="angle-japhet one"  src="http://stretchflex.net/photos/startAngle.png" min-height="25%" width="100%"/>
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-pad mov">
        <div class="bordered-image child second">
          <span class="swing-area">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 no-pad">
              <img class="swing" src="http://stretchflex.net/japhet1.jpg" min-height="50%" width="86%"/>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-pad ang3">
              <div class="red-ex">  
                <span class="red">&#10008;</span>
              </div>
              <div class="sec-ang-3">
                <img class="angle-japhet sec" src="http://stretchflex.net/photos/japhetAngle.png" min-height="25%" width="100%" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
          <span class="swing-area jav">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 no-pad">
              <img class="swing" src="http://stretchflex.net/javier1.jpg" min-height="50%" width="86.5%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 no-pad ang4">
            <div class="green-check">
                <span class="green">&#10004;</span>
              </div>
              <div class="sec-ang-4">
                <img class="angle-japhet sec" src="http://stretchflex.net/photos/javierAngle.png" min-height="25%" width="100%" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-pad">
        <div class="bordered-image child description third">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 delt" style="text-align: center;">
          <h1>`\Delta degrees`</h1>
        </div>
          <div class="metrics">
            <table class="fir">
              <tr class="fir col-xs-12">
                <th class="fir col-xs-6">Name</th>
                <th class="fir col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 100px;">Height</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fir col-xs-12">
                <td class="fir col-xs-6">Japhet Amador</td>
                <td class="fir col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 118px;">6'4"</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="fir col-xs-12">
                <td class="fir col-xs-6">Javier Baez</td>
                <td class="fir col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 118px;">6'0"</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="sec col-xs-12">
              <tr class="sec col-xs-12">
                <th class="sec col-xs-6">Weight</th>
                <th class="sec col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 40px;">Home Runs (2014)</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="sec col-xs-12">
                <td class="sec col-xs-6">310</td>
                <td class="sec col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 125px;">14</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="sec col-xs-12">
                <td class="sec col-xs-6">190</td>
                <td class="sec col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 125px;">32</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="pelvis">
          <img class="pelvis-1" src="http://stretchflex.net/pelvis1.jpg" />
          <img class="arrow" src="http://stretchflex.net/rotArrow4.jpeg" />
          <img class="pelvis-2" src="http://stretchflex.net/pelvis2.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 no-pad" style="height: 300px;">
  <div class="started col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
    <a href="http://stretchflex.net/AppPt1(revised).html" class="button button-glow button-border button-rounded button-primary">Get Started</a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Will do. One moment...

Comment: I'm seeing this error: `[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module stretchFlexViewer...`

Comment: FrankerZ I have added the error as well as included what I would like to happen :)

Comment: You should attach the Router with the main module (the auto bootstrapping module). You are bootstrapping your application with "stretchFlexViewer" but you have set the routeProvider in the module "app" which does not seem correct and also the app module will not bootstrap by itself.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. I have changed the ng-app in my index file to app. However you say "the app module will not bootstrap by itself". What do you mean by this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3TN3zngNlEoducI0KXw1?p=preview)

Changes made:

1. `<html ng-app="app" lang="en">` The name of your main module is `app`.
2. Included the scripts.

Scripts:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"> .   </script>
<script data-require="angular-route@1.6.0" data-semver="1.6.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="homeCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="stretchProdCtrl.js"></script>
```

3. Declared one dependency of `app`.

Module definition:

`angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]) // ng-app="app" to match here`

4. Referenced that module like so:

Reference main module:

`angular.module("app").controller('homeCtrl'`

Comment: You are the man! For some reason all I can see is the preview window. How can I see the code? Will give you green check immediately

Comment: Yes it does. Thank You!

Comment: No problem.  Also, as a side note, AngularJS does include jQuery Lite.  Take a look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element . Try to write your code without jQuery.  You don't need it, and it will save you a lot of problems down the road with Angular's `$scope` updates.

Comment: @RyeGuy One last thing.  Have a look at John Papa's style guide.  It's amazing, and it helped me to understand how to get organized in AngularJS.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: Hey Raphael hate to bring this back up after you have already solved this. But what changes would I have to make if I want the index.html to be the layout view for every page and the rest of the html simply partials?

Comment: @RyeGuy Can you ask a new question and tag me in the comments?  Also, please update the plunkr to show me exactly where you're having trouble.